# Show that $2^a + 1 $ is divisible by 3 if a is odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I understand that this question has been asked before, but I was wondering if I could get clarification in understanding the accepted answer by @Hagen von Eitzen. (Sorry no plagiarism here is intended, just want to clarify my understanding):

> If $k=2m$, then $2^k=4^m≡1^m\pmod 3$ and if $k=2m+1 $
>
> then $2^k=2⋅4^m≡2⋅1^m\pmod 3$

I understand each step of this answer, except how it relates to the question of $2^a + 1$ being divisible by 3?

From my understanding of the definition of modular congruence, the last part of the answer is the same as $ 3|(2 \cdot 4^m - 2 \cdot 1^m)$.

This seems clear to me with the coprime cancellation rule - but I don't see how to go from this step to concluding that $2^a + 1$ is divisible by 3 when a is odd?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could give me an explanation in 'plain english'?

Many Thanks!!

Comment: Since $1^m = 1$, you get $2^{2m+1}+1 \equiv 2\cdot 1^m + 1 \equiv 2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: $3|(2^a+1)\Leftrightarrow 2^a+1\equiv0\bmod3\Leftrightarrow 2^a\equiv2\bmod 3\Leftrightarrow a~\rm odd$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the second, when $k$ is odd, $$3\mid (2 \cdot 4^m - 2 \cdot 1^m) \iff 3\mid (2\cdot 4^m - 2) \iff 3\mid (2(4^m - 1))$$

Can you show that $3\mid 4^m - 1$? (See the case of even $a$: $2^k=4^m≡1^m\equiv 1(\mod3)$, so $4^m - 1 \equiv 1 - 1\equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

Put differently, for odd $a$:

$$2^a + 1 \iff 2^{2m+1} + 1 \equiv 2\cdot 1^m + 1 \equiv 2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$

Comment: Many thanks for explaining each step, your answer is very helpful and clear. Can I just clarify: is it correct that that the congruence operator can be treated like an equality? So what I read from your last line is that since $2^{2m+1} + 1 $ is congruent to $2 \cdot 1^m + 1 $ and that is congruent to 3 which is obviously congruent to 0, then we have that $2^a + 1$ is congruent to 0, so divisible by 3?

Comment: Exactly. $2^a + 1$ is indeed congruent to $0$, mod 3, so $3$ divides $2^a + 1 - 0 = 2^a + 1$, for *odd* a.

Answer (score 0):

I will give an outline.

Let the statement be
$$P(a) =2^a  + 1$$
The statement becomes true for  $a= 1$

Let it be true for some odd integer $k$ so that $$P(k) \equiv 0 \ (\mathrm{mod}\ 3)$$

For $k+2$, (the next odd integer)
if it evaluates to be true that

$$P(k+2) - P(k) \equiv 0 \ (\mathrm{mod}\ 3)$$

then,

$$\begin{align} P(k+2)-P(k) &= 2^{k+2}-2^k \\& = 3  \cdot 2^k \end{align} $$

which is true and by applying induction you can prove it.